# NoMethodError in Reviews#new after clicking on a link to create review page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

- **Error** happens after clicking the `Submit a Review` link from restaurants/show.html.erb

```
Showing ...app/views/reviews/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `reviews_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000006c20>

1:  <%= simple_form_for [@restaurant, @review] do |f| %>
2:   <%= f.input :rating %>
3:   <%= f.input :content %>
4:   <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
5:  <% end %>
```

- **Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_01_11_104035) do

  create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "rating"
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "restaurant_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["restaurant_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_restaurant_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "reviews", "restaurants"
end
```

- **Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'restaurants#index'
  resources :restaurants, only: [ :index, :new, :create, :show ] do
    resources :reviews, only: [ :new, :create ]
  end
end
```

```
               Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
                 root GET  /                                                 restaurants#index
   restaurant_reviews POST /restaurants/:restaurant_id/reviews(.:format)     reviews#create
new_restaurant_review GET  /restaurants/:restaurant_id/reviews/new(.:format) reviews#new
          restaurants GET  /restaurants(.:format)                            restaurants#index
                      POST /restaurants(.:format)                            restaurants#create
       new_restaurant GET  /restaurants/new(.:format)                        restaurants#new
           restaurant GET  /restaurants/:id(.:format)                        restaurants#show
```

- **Controllers**

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
  end

  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  def create
    restaurant = Restaurant.new(strong_params)
    restaurant.category.downcase!
    if restaurant.save
      redirect_to restaurants_path
    else
      render new_restaurant_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def strong_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :address, :phone_number, :category)
  end
end
```

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(strong_params)
    @review.restaurant = @restaurant
    if @review.save
      redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def strong_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :content)
  end
end
```

- **Views**

```
<%# restaurants/show.html.erb %>
<div class="show-resto-container ">
  <h1 class="page-headers">
  <%= @restaurant.name %>'s Reviews
  <%= link_to new_restaurant_review_path(@restaurant), class: "btn btn-primary .btn-lg" do %>
    <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i> Submit a Review
  <% end %>
  </h1>

  <div class="resto-reviews-container">
    
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <% @restaurant.reviews.each do |review| %>
      <li class="list-group-item">
      <p><%= review.print_stars %></p>
      <p><%= review.content %></p>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
```

```
<%# reviews/new.html.erb %>
<%= simple_form_for [@restaurant, @review] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :rating %>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure `@restaurant` is set in `reviews/new.html.erb`. I suspect `@restaurant` is nil.

Comment: @SampatBadhe you've made me realize that the previous project I was referencing to had a `before_action` to fetch the @restaurant. Was able to get it working. Thanks a lot!